# calculating hashes on-the-fly during download

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I have the following code that does download a file from the internet and saves it somewhere:

```
class Foo
{
    private static Uri _url;
    private static string _filepath;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _url = new Uri("http://www.speedtest.qsc.de/1MB.qsc");
        _filepath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + Path.GetFileName(_url.LocalPath);
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {                
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += _bar;
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(_url, _filepath);               
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void _bar (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(_filepath))
            {
                md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I’d like to compute MD5 and SHA1 for the file. I can do that easily by opening a FileStream after the download has completed and use that to compute the hash. However, that is quite inefficient for large files at least.

What I really would like to do is to calculate them already during download by updating the hash after a new block of bytes has been retrieved (with TransformBlock method).

Is there some event of WebClient I can subscribe to, to get the byte blocks and then update both hashes? Should I use some other class like WebRequest? I need the total number of bytes to read too in order to display some download progress information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for this.

The idea is that you set up your request and then call [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx). You then begin reading from the response stream and storing to file. As you receive each block and before you send it to the file, you can use the data to compute the hash.

The MSDN page for `BeginGetResponse` shows how to do it for an HTML page. You would change that a bit to read the data as binary rather than text, and rather than appending to a `StringBuilder`, you would write the data to a file.

If what you're downloading is small enough to fit comfortably in memory, you could use [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144191.aspx), and then compute the hash from that memory block before saving it to file.

Comment: I ended up using the `ResponseStream` of a `WebRequest` and reading the chunks in a loop with `await remoteStream.ReadAsync` (+ `TransformBlock` as mentioned above) instead of manual callbacks, but your answer is right of course.